# get sql server 2005 to NOT use unicode in its TDS protocol?

Tags: sql-server-2005

This may be a really stupid question, but...

The [TDS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) used by sql server appears to use unicode or UTF-16 character encoding. A query like `select foo from bar` appears like 
`s.e.l.e.c.t. .f.o.o. .f.r.o.m. .b.a.r` in the tcp stream in wireshark.

If you have an application connecting to SQL server over a network, that absolutely does not and probably never will use unicode text fields, is there a way to tell the sql client to encode the queries in ascii to cut network traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tabular data stream (TDS) protocol documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/e/6/ae6e4142-aa58-45c6-8dcf-a657e5900cd3/%5BMS-TDS%5D.pdf) specifically states that SQL statements in the protocol will be encoded in Unicode (section 2.2). Unless you're running over a heavily bandwidth-constrained network you're probably just gold-plating to worry about this. (If you are bandwidth-constrained to the point that this is a problem you might want to consider tunneling the traffic over something with compression.)

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this which seems to do some sort of compression on sql server tds traffic:

http://www.nitrosphere.net/store/nitroaccelerator

My initial test have shown that it works very well but it is quite expensive.